# Getting a runtime NZEC error although the public test cases are passing

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

> t = int(input()) for i in  range(t):   n = int(input())   c =
> input().split(" ")   k = len(c)   d = {}   for i in range(k):
> d[i+1] = int(c[i])   q = int(input())   for i in range(q):
> count  = 0
> id = input().split(" ")
> for i in range (len(id)):
> id[i] = int(id[i])
> for i in range(id[0],id[-1]+1):
> count+= d[i]
> print(count)

Getting a runtime error on CodeChef (NZEC) although the public test cases are passing. Tried using it on Replit as well and seems to be working fine. Unable to fix the error since early morning.Can anyone pl help me fix the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include what runtime error you're having.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, the code you posted is invalid. Indentation is vitally important in Python so please edit your question and format your code using the triple backtick syntax.